# Using gitignore only for a subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have the following (simplified) git repo for a project using SpecFlow:

```
/repo
    /code
        /code.cs
    /specifications
        /spec.feature
        /spec.feature.cs
```

I'd like to have two repos, with the new one just containing the *.feature files. This would then be included in the original repo as a subtree. This is so that only testers need to worry about the code, and every else can use the project with just the *.feature files.

I've managed to get a subtree set up, but the last hurdle is ensuring that only *.feature files are committed to the subtree repo. A .gitignore file applies to both projects (unless I'm mis-using it) and so doesn't help. Is there a way I can ignore all but *.feature files for the subtree only?

Comment: Why not putting a .gitignore in your subtree?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, I'm sure I tried that but it works now. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Considering how a `.gitignore` works, it should be as easy as putting one in the subfolder repo where you don't want to see `*.feature.cs` files.

That `.gitginore` can include the `*.feature`  rule and would apply only to the subtree and its subfolders.

Here:

```
/repo/code/.gitignore
/repo/specifications/spec.feature/.gitignore
```

Putting it on parent folders would hide too many `feature.cs` files.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I was too hasty: I have /specifications/features with the single line "*.feature.cs" which works for the subtree, but also ignores the "*.feature.cs" files in the /repo directory. Did I misunderstand what you suggested?

Comment: @DeanBarnes if that `.gitignore` is a file in the subtree, its effect won't be visible in the parent repo. It only applies in the subfolders of the directory in which the `.gitignore` is created.

Comment: with the `.gitignore` file in `/repo/specifications`, `git status` in `/repo` doesn't show the `*.feature.cs` files but does if `.gitignore` is removed. Is there an extra step to localise the settings to the subtree?

Comment: @DeanBarnes a `.gitignore` *never* applies upward. Always downward. Is your `feature.cs` file in `/repo`? or in 
with the `.gitignore` file in `/repo/specifications`? Do I understand correctly that `/repo/specifications` is your subtree?

Comment: the `feature.cs` files are twinned with `feature` files and are stored in the same directory as the `feature` file, but the subtree repo should only contain the `feature` files. `/repo/specifications` is indeed the subtree, and is where I put the `.gitignore` file

Comment: @DeanBarnes then the `.gitignore` will only apply to `/repo/specifications`, not to `/repo`. That is how `.gitignore` works. Remember that you need to `git rm --cache` the feature files if they were already versionned before the `.gitignore` can ignore them.

Comment: It does only apply to `repo/specifications`, but means that the main git repo is also ignoring `feature.cs` files. This is the problem I'm trying to work around.

Comment: @DeanBarnes do you have any other `.gitignore` or `.gitattributes` files at the `/repo` (the "main repo") level?

Comment: I don't, and removing the `repo/specifications/.gitignore` means `*.feature.cs` files appear after `git status`

Comment: The `*.feature.cs` which are in a *parent* folder of `/repo/specifications`? (where the `.gitignore` was before you removed it). Ie that were in `/repo`?

Comment: The arrangement is like in the question itself, but with the addition of `/repo/specifications/.gitignore`

Comment: @DeanBarnes well... in your original question, you don't mention those `*.feature.cs` in `/repo`, only in `/repo/specification`. Please edit your question to specify *exactly* what should be where, and what should be ignored where.

Comment: There are no `*.feature.cs` files in `/repo`, only `/repo/specification`. The arrangement in the question is correct.

Comment: @DeanBarnes then the .gigignore works as expected. If putting it in /repo/specifications hides too many file, then you would need to put in the subfolder where you don't want to see the `*.feature.cs` files: `/repo/specifications/code`. I will edit the answer.